# JAX-RS canceling running Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, jax-rs

I am working on a JAX-RS REST application.

I hope I'm right that every request is using a new thread. But I want, if a new thread is created, that the old thread gets interrupted and only the new thread is running. So every time a request is made, only one thread is running. Is it possible to stop an existing thread in JAX-RS?

Comment: It's probably a pool of threads that reuses threads instead of new ones all the time. And why do you want to stop threads? Servers are supposed to process many requests in parallel or you would need 1 per user.

Comment: its because im using the Java.sound.sample on the Server side. so the System gets a call and the user can hear Sound data. but when 2 threads accesses the SourceDataLine, the line is unavailable and the first thread is not get cancled and the Audio Output is not working anymore.

Comment: I am also insterested in this question. I have a service and one of the routes map to a function that calculates a schedule, which can take a huge amount of time, so I'd want to be able to kill that thread somehow.

Comment: @dabadaba There is [asynchronous support](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html) for your use case